# Steam won't run on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal

Tags: steam

Here's how I installed steam:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install steam
```

If I run steam:

```
$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
```

Then a window pops up and steam downloads an update and extracts it and then: `Fatal Error: Failed to load steamui.so`

```
cat: '/home/myuser/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.tar.xz.part*': No such file or directory
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/myuser/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?